# Why are signals not raised in this example code on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I'm trying to understand the following example code about signals:

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

sig_atomic_t sigusr1_count = 0;

void handler(int signal_number) {
    ++sigusr1_count;
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_handler = &handler;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL );
    printf("SIGUSR1 was raised %d times\n", sigusr1_count);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
SIGUSR1 was raised 0 times
```

Why was the signal not raised?

Comment: Well, did either the "lengthy stuff" or any other process perform a `kill` with `SIGUSR1` on this process?

Comment: @larsmans no, sorry, that was a comment in the example code in the book too, not a code. The code posted above is "as is" in the book.

Comment: @TomBrito: Then that's a bad book...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons. The first, is that nothing ever sends SIGUSR1 to your process. The other, more important one, is that you don't give any time for anyone to do so. Immediately after registering your signal handler, you print out how many times the signal was received in, most likely, less then a few milliseconds. You need to add something like `sleep(10)` before printing out the result.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is nothing sending the `SIGUSR1` signal to your application? Did you try running `kill -USR1 pid` to send the signal? Or `kill(pid, SIGUSR1)` from this or another application?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you send the signal `SIGUSR1`? You should sens it after `sigaction` and before `printf`... Add a loop in your `main` function.